# Contact Form 7 - Create dynamic pipes and use label not value in email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use the following script to create a select-list out of a custom post type. In the email which is sent after the form submit i use both tags "offers-private] & [_raw_offers-private]" (field-name in contact-form 7). Both tags return the post-id and not the title of the post. In the email i need to see the post-title (select-value) and not the id (select-id).

```
function dynamic_select_field_values ( $scanned_tag, $replace ) {  
  
    if ( $scanned_tag['name'] != 'offers-school' and $scanned_tag['name'] != 'offers-private' )  
        return $scanned_tag;

        $rows = get_posts(
            array ( 
                'post_type' => 'offers',  
                'numberposts' => -1,  
                'orderby' => 'title',  
                'order' => 'ASC'
            )
        );  
    
    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {  
        $scanned_tag['values'][] = $row->ID;  
        $scanned_tag['labels'][] = $row->post_title;  
    }

    $pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes($scanned_tag['values']);

    $scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_befores();
    $scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes;
  
    return $scanned_tag;  
}  

add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_select_field_values', 10, 2);
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I've read your question a few times, and still don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: Contact form 7 sends a mail and i use the tag [offers-private] which in my opinion should return the title (label) of the selected option in the select field. But in the email i just always get the value back.

Comment: That filter isn't used during submission of the form in the way you want.  I think you should consider making your own form tag instead.